# does this code about arrays make any sense?

Tags: java, arrays

I am watching a lecture from the University of California at Berkeley about creating arrays in Java.  The professor presents the following code, and claims the code will create fractions such as 1/6, 2/6, etc.  (I added main() so it can be tested.)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fraction[] f = new Fraction[5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
          f[i] = new Fraction(i, 6);
        }

    }
}
```

I am testing this in Eclipse, obviously the code does not compile since there is no class Fraction, and even if I change Fraction to double the code still will not produce any fractions.

I am guessing the professor intended to write this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] f = new double[5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
          f[i] = (i/6);
        }

    }
}
```

Is my reasoning correct?

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGibp2L5uCc  @12:25
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf98/labs/lab2/Fraction.java

Comment: Obviously fraction is a user defined class as StephenTG has posted.  Obviously these lectures may include material covered in labs and in homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that this will start at `0/6`, not `1/6`. Second of all, the professor is most probably referring to a hypothetical `Fraction` class that stores *exact* fractions (i.e. a numerator and a denominator as two `int`s); a `double` cannot do this.

Now, if you want to use doubles (which will not store exact fractions per se but rather the approximate numbers they represent), you have to use double division (and not integer division, as you are currently performing):

```
f[i] = i/6.0;
```

---

As @StephenTG points out, the `Fraction` class seems to be implemented [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf98/labs/lab2/Fraction.java).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the `Fraction` class has a method to return a `double` or a `float`, it can be very well constructed with `int` actually.

Then the internal logics will take care of processing and returning the correct type.

Consider this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Fraction(1, 6).getFraction());
}
static class Fraction {
    private float fraction;
    public Fraction(int num, int den) {
        // TODO check that den != 0, otherwise we're in a world of trouble :D
        fraction = (float) num/den;
    }
    public float getFraction() {
        return fraction;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.16666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. This:

```
f[i] = new Fraction(i, 6);
```

Means

> Store on position i of the f array, this fraction object

`f` is a `Fraction[]`, meaning that each index contains a `Fraction` typed object. You need to create a new one (i.e. `new Ftaction(1,6)`) in order to store `1/6`. You were right about **what** to store, you just were not getting the whole picture about **how** do you represent it.

Just for the sake of your class, I assume that `Fraction` is a type created by your teacher and that you have to include in your project *(As others have correctly suggested, you might be searching for [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf98/labs/lab2/Fraction.java) class)*

Answer (score 1):

There is fraction class here:
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf98/labs/lab2/Fraction.java

I assume this is part of your class as well.
You have to download this file and add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `Fraction` class in order to create an array of `Fraction` objects.

From StephenTG's comment, it looks like you need to import [`Fraction.java`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf98/labs/lab2/Fraction.java) into eclipse.

(This Fraction.java has a `main` method for testing purposes.  You can place your code in that method, or you need to remove that method if you want to use your own `main` method.)

Answer (score 0):

You should define a *Fraction* class first:

```
public class Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    public Fraction(){}

    /* watch out for a division by zero Exception! 
     * maybe throw a custom exception here
    */
    public Fraction(int n, int d){
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }

    public float getValue(){
       return numerator * 1.0f/denominator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your first snippet will only make sense if your `Fraction` class has a `constructor` that takes two integer values (e.g.):

```
class Fraction
{
    private int val1, val2;

    public Fraction(int val1, int val2)
    {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }
}
```

For your second part of the question, your loop will first `return` an `integer` and then `type-cast` it to `double`. So, the result in your case will always be zero, even though you know it shouldn't. To fix this, any of the following two lines of code will do.

```
f[i] = ((i + 0.0)/6);
```

or

```
f[i] = (i/6.0);
```